# How to get ANDROID_ID with Frida

Tags: java, android, frida

The [ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) is unique in each application in Android.

To get the `ANDROID_ID` with Java inside Android I amd using this code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.provider.Settings;
protected void onCreate(...) {
  context = (Context)this;
  String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString((ContentResolver)context.getContentResolver(), (String)"android_id");
}
```

But I want to run it inside some other application on my andoird phone.
I wanted to use [Frida](https://www.frida.re/) for this.

I am loading my injected script with Python:

```
import frida
device = frida.get_usb_device()
pid = device.spawn(["com.target.app"])
device.resume(pid)
time.sleep(1) #Without it Java.perform silently fails
session = device.attach(pid)
script = session.create_script(open("jsfrida.js").read())
script.load()

#prevent the python script from terminating
raw_input()
```

But inside my script I don't understand how to call it, this is what I tried:

```
Java.perform(function (){
  console.log("Inside java perform function");
  var ActivityThread = Java.use('android.app.ActivityThread');
  var Context = Java.use('android.content.Context');
  var settings = Java.use('android.provider.Settings.Secure');
  var ctx = Java.cast(ActivityThread.currentApplication().getApplicationContext(), Context);
  //console.log(ctx.getPackageName());
  //console.log(ctx.getContentResolver());
  var androidId = settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), "android_id");
  console.log(androidId);
  console.log("END");
 });
```

But it doesn't print the `androidId`, it only prints:

```
Script loaded successfully 
Inside java perform function
```

Comment: I think your problem is the context. You can't create a new context, you have to use an existing one. To get an existing context you need to hook a function that retrieves the context as a parameter.

Comment: @Robert you are right. I fixed the context issue, I now have context (I verified it with the commented lines), but still have problem with the `Setting` class.

Comment: I remember some issues with subclasses like `Settings.Secure` in frida the class name may be different. Print the complete class list for classes which name start with `android.provider` and see if the class name is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54149567/150978

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Secure](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#4744) is inner class so you need to use `$`

  - [inner classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11388863/2655092) will be compiled to ClassName$InnerClassName
- To get `CotentResolver` you can invoke `getContentResolver` without casting.

```
$ frida -Uf com.app.example --no-pause
     ____
    / _  |   Frida 12.1.2 - A world-class dynamic instrumentation toolkit
   | (_| |
    > _  |   Commands:
   /_/ |_|       help      -> Displays the help system
   . . . .       object?   -> Display information about 'object'
   . . . .       exit/quit -> Exit
   . . . .
   . . . .   More info at http://www.frida.re/docs/home/
Spawned `com.app.example`. Resuming main thread!                    
[Android::com.app.example]-> 
function getContext() {
  return Java.use('android.app.ActivityThread').currentApplication().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
}                                         
function logAndroidId() {
  console.log('[?]', Java.use('android.provider.Settings$Secure').getString(getContext(), 'android_id'));
}
undefined
[Android::com.app.example]-> Java.perform(logAndroidId)
[?] 52d1497b52bf8a11
undefined
[Android::com.app.example]->
```